# UIImage memory different between simulator and real device

Tags: ios, swift, memory, uikit, uiimage

[image]
Hi,
Asking something about memory usage difference between simulator(iPhone 14 pro) and my Real device(iPhone 12 mini).

The troublemaker code is here

```swift
@objc func handlePan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = sender.translation(in: view)
        let progress = translation.x / view.bounds.width
        //print(translation.x)
        switch sender.state {
        case .began:
            previousImageNumber = imageNumber
            previousPanDirection = .none
            previousRotationAngle = currentRotationAngle
        case .changed:
            let currentPanDirection: PanDirection = progress > 0 ? .right : .left
            
            currentRotationAngle = previousRotationAngle + 2 * .pi * progress
            imageNumber = previousImageNumber - Int(round(currentRotationAngle / (2 * .pi / 60)))
            imageNumber %= 60
            
            if imageNumber <= 0 {
                imageNumber += 60
            }
            
            let imageNumStr = converter()
            
            imageView.image = nil // **I expected UIImage to be nil. Memory in simulator doesn't increase, but real device not.**
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image_" + imageNumStr) 
            
            previousPanDirection = currentPanDirection
        case .ended:
            currentRotationAngle = 0
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

Like above code, I expected the UIImage in heap will be deallocated.
Because My simulator`s memory doesn't increase.
[image]

[image]

But, When I run on my real device and pan gesture begin, the memory kick the roof.

So, I have two questions.

1. Why UIImage memory not deallocated after I called "imageView.image = nil"?
2. Why Different memory status between my simulator and real device?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Because images created with `UIImage(named:)` are cached.
2. Because the simulator is not a device.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!! But, I wonder the UIImage instance was in heap, but after I called the "imageView.image = nil", the image is class(NSObject) So I thought deallocated is sure. But .. Is there any things I don't know?

Comment: Clearly yes. Try to understand what "cached" means. It means that even if you have no more references to the image, it remains held by the runtime in memory. It is possible to load a UIImage in a way that does not cache, but you are not doing that. Watch https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/416/